# How is an Object-Variable managed when it is sent ByRef to a service for processing?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf-ria-services, wcf-data-services

### **Server at location A**

I have a Service hosted which will **process array received(ByRef)** .

### **Client Computer at Location B**

I have a method in the application which will take strings from the user, add it to the array object and call the ServiceMethod to have the Array processed(which is passed ByRef), then i will show you the
result on screen.

***What i Understand***

When any thing is passed by reference, the memory location is passed therefore any action taken on the "thing" is taken on the location of the "thing".

### ***Question***

*For the "thing" to be on the same PC/Memory its okay. but*

What happens when the "thing" is on a different PC? What does the Receiver do? Does it access the memory bit by bit of the sender which is thousands of miles away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the very precise scenario. *Regular* WCF will generally interpret `ref` as a "serialize this data to the service, let the service play with it, then serialize the data back to the client" - so the *semantic* of `ref` is then similar, but the implementation is very different. During usage, the server is only talking to the local copy of the data, so there is no huge performance issue - *however*, if you send a huge `byte[]` and then only access 2 bytes from it, is still has to send all that data *twice* (both directions).